# How to run jobScheduler even the phone is on doze mode

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-jobscheduler

How can I run JobScheduler to work even if device is on doze mode. Or I need to use something else? I know also for AlarmManager but like I read the JobScheduler is new and better approach than AlarmManager for background tasks.
I need to perform some task to check the database for new data.
And I need to be much often like every 5 minutes or maybe much often (I know that JobScheduler run min every 15 minutes). But If is some way to make more often and also in every phone mode when wifi network is on.

I can't use FCM. The app and server are on Internal network

Comment: look into Work Manager instead of job scheduler.... does the same stuff but is easier to manage

Comment: basically it is jobscheduler v2.0 by google

Comment: Do you have some good sample to see or tutorial how it works Work Manager?

Comment: google it, there's plenty

Comment: Does AlarmManager is better than WorkManager for my work because WorkManager and JobScheduler minimum repeating time is 15minutes.
But AlarmManager like I read, scheduling need to be reset after restarting the device.

Answer (score 0):

Yes in alarms you'll have to write a boot complete broadcast receiver. If it's less than 15 for you, yea go with alarms... But beware of the doze mode

Comment: But AlarmManager don't work after usually 2 hours (I tested repeatedly every minute with pushing a notification). I don't understand how can I achieve this.

Comment: as far as my testing goes, alarms work just fine, it's just that post android M, it becomes a bit tricky due to doze mode